# fitBounds() is not working with geocoder function

Tags: google-geocoder, fitbounds

I have just updated my code from v2 to v3. Every thing is working but the function `map.fitBounds();`
Here is my sample code

> ```
>    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
>
>    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'your address'}, >function(results, status) { 
>        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
>
>            var newPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), >results[0].geometry.location.lng());
>            markerBounds.extend(newPoint); 
>
>            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
>                map: map,  
>                position: results[0].geometry.location 
>            }); 
>  
>        } else { 
>            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status); 
>        } 
>    }); 
>
>    map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
> ```
>
> }

I have found that this code looks fine but here fitBounds() will not work. The required change is mention in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case we have to write code like this

> markerBounds.extend(newPoint);
>   map.fitBounds(markerBounds); // here in function rather in the end

This worked for me hopefully will work for you as well.